# Chinese film about time travel where travelers must very move slowly while in transit

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Saw it around the end of 90's on TV. The most unique scene is when a man and a woman is travelling (seemingly in hurry/panic) with other travelers (they might be stranded) around them. The man is experienced with the method and warns her to not move too fast. He told about spending a long periods just to take his nose back. When he prevents her fall, he warns her to not laugh, and there's another scene where the laughing travelers explode. The method seems to be related to electricity: incandescent bulbs are shown prominently. One of the time periods they visit is at least before the computer era in crowded Chinese-looking city, when they are being chased and had to escape using the time travel method.

Comment: Was the film in Chinese, or merely set in China?

Comment: Could this be *Love in the Time of Twilight*?

Comment: It's Chinese (or at least the actors are). Can't pin it to mainland, hongkong or Taiwan though. Oh... correct!!! It's Love in the Time of Twilight. Please post it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Could this be *[Love in the Time of Twilight](http://hkmdb.com/db/movies/view.mhtml?id=7996&display_set=eng)*?

[image]

According to [this](http://www.lovehkfilm.com/reviews_2/love_in_the_time_of_twilight.htm) plot description:

> **Young and Wu are able to travel back in time thanks to the magic of
>   the lightbulb,** which is a plot device that requires explaining. You
>   see, when a lightbulb is turned on, the electricity allows a
>   supernatural being (like Wu's ghostly form) to travel through all
>   facets of time in which that lightbulb existed. **While in the lightbulb
>   world, you must move very slowly**, or your body will fly into pieces.
>   And, if the lightbulb is ever destroyed while you're trapped inside,
>   you can kiss reincarnation or any further time travel goodbye.

Comment: A great film! It's also wonderfully funny too. Directed by Tsui Hark, one of Hong Kong's great directors.